# How to use Regular expression to split string (HL700X-FILENAME DDSA-RECIEVERNAME-1) in Java?

Tags: java, regex, split

We are getting file name in following format.

```
String a = "HL700X-FILENAME DDSA-RECIEVERNAME-1.pdf"
a.split("DD(?:**)-"); ??
```

Here we need to fetch RECIEVERNAME.

We need to keep in mind the following conditions about file name:

1) Receiver name consists of Hyphen too. (So can't split on base of hyphens only)

2) DDSA is name of an organization and it can be different with DD as perfix like DDMA, DDTA, DDGA which means DD is common in all. Also, There is only one organization which is different i.e KRK.

3) File Name is also custom means user can enter anything

What regular expression should i use to split String between following:

```
A) DD**- & Last Hyphen. 
B) KRK- & Last Hyphen.
```

*UPDATE*:

a.split("DD..-|KRK-");

Comment: Literally use `String#split` which accepts a regex argument

Comment: That i understand but Unable to find how to do that.

Comment: `"myString".split("myRegex");`

Comment: I have re framed the question for better understanding. I am looking for regular expressions which will do the above.

Comment: do you want the RECIEVERNAME ?

Comment: Yes but there are some conditions which i mentioned.

Comment: Is it allowed to have blanks in the filename or receivername? If yes the format is ambiguous: `HL700X-foo DDSA-bar KRK-baz-1.pdf`. What would be the receivername in this case?

Comment: The fixed format is that RECEIVER NAME will always end with -1 ; Also RECIEVER NAME will be attached to FILE NAME using - like DDSA-

Comment: This does not solve the ambiguity. In my example above is the receivername `bar KRK-baz` or `baz`?

Comment: RECIEVER NAME will never contain KRK- or DDSA- | but file name can have them

Comment: @fatherazrael What are FM and SRF?

Comment: Should be OK unless `-1` can appear in receivername. Better remove the last hyphen and everything after it.

Comment: Thanks Henry for suggestions.

Comment: @NaveedS : Sorry, i am trying with some other similar string. I have removed confusing comment :)

Comment: @fatherazrael Can you check if what I have mentioned below is what you require?

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch RECIEVERNAME using Matcher

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?:DD\\w+|KRK)-(.*)-");

    String[] test = new String[]{"HL700X-FILENAME DDSA-RECIEVERNAME-1.pdf", "HL700X-FILENAME KRK-RECIEVERNAME-1.pdf"};

    for (String data : test) {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(data);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. But What if file name become -> HL700X-FILEDDSA-NAME DDSA-RECIEVERNAME-1.pdf  . As i have mentioned that File name is custom. But Reciever name is not custom so it will not contains Organization name. But File name is custom so end user can enter organization name which can create problem. So we need to always pick the last DDSA-  or KRK.

Answer (score 0):

This one should help:

```
.+(?:DDSA|KKR)-(?!DDSA|KKR)(.+)-.+
```

Capturing the first group using `$1` should give you the part between the sequence of last DDSA/KKR followed by hyphen and last hyphen. Hope that it is what you need.

Tried it this way:

```
    String[] strings = new String[]{"HL700X-FILENAME DDSA-RECIEVERNAME-1.pdf", "HL700X-DDSA1-NAME KKR-RECIEVERNAME-1.pdf",
            "HL700X-FILENAME KKR-RECIEVERNAME-1.pdf", "HL700X-DDSAa - 2-NAME KKR-RECIEVERNAME-1.pdf"};
    String regex = ".+(?:DDSA|KKR)-(?!DDSA|KKR)(.+)-.+";
    for (String s:strings) {
        System.out.println(s.replaceAll(regex, "$1"));
    }
```